# CV2: Is there a function that outputs the number of white dots in a polygon?

Tags: python, opencv

I do a "Background Subtraction" with a VideoStream. Then I want to check inside the interior of a specified polygon, if there are white dots.

I thought about using https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/point_polygon_test/point_polygon_test.html but I don't know how to do it, because the white points are existing after applying the filter. The original stream contains also white points which I also dont't want to count.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture() 
cap.open("rtsp://LOGINNAME:PASSWORD@192.168.178.42:554")
#cap.open("C:\\Users\\001\\Desktop\\cam-20191025-220508-220530.mp4")

fgbg = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()

while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    polygonInnenAutoErkennen_cnt = np.array( [(24, 719), (714,414), (1005,429),(1084,719)] )
    cv2.drawContours(fgmask,[polygonInnenAutoErkennen_cnt],-1,(255,128,60))
    #How can I check here?
    cv2.imshow('frame',fgmask)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27: # exit on ESC
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Convert your image to binary using `cv2.threshold()`, `cv2.adaptiveThreshold()`, or `cv2.Canny()`. This will give you a mask image where the pixels are either 0 or 255. From here you can use `cv2.countNonZero()` to count the number of white pixels on the mask. Note this will count ALL white pixels on the mask, if you wanted only a certain portion you will have to use contour filtering to extract the desired region

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use mask image. Plot your polygon on binary image, and use it as mask for your white dots. You can just do per-pixel multiplication or logical AND.